# What happens to data sent but not received with the Receive method?

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a basic question that has come up, so I would like to ask them.

If I implement a server and a client, and one of them sends 'N' number of data but the other side does not invoke the `Receive` method, where does the transmitted data exist?

I have implemented a simple server and client, where one of them periodically sends data using the `Send` method, and the other continuously invokes `Receive` at after a specific timing.

Although I haven't confirmed with a large amount of data, I was able to receive a stable sequential transmission of up to approximately 2000 items.

As soon as I started invoking `Receive`, a total of 2000 data (each 1024 bytes) were received along with the subsequent data 2001 and 2002 in sequential order.

I am curious about the origin of the preceding approximately 2000 data received before invoking `Receive`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the networking stack has buffers at various levels that can store a certain amount of data.

When data is received by the network card, it buffers that data (either directly into RAM, using DMA protocols, completely bypassing the CPU, or in internal buffers on the card). It then signals (interrupts) the CPU that data is available.

The CPU stops what it's doing and allows the network driver and kernel to deal with the data. The kernel then looks up what TCP sockets are open so it knows where to send the data. The appropriate user-mode application normally has a waiting thread, that gets woken up to receive the data (this all happens *within* the `Receive` method).

When the `Receive` is woken up to complete, it will request that the data is copied into a user-mode buffer (usually supplied by you from C#, although there can often be more levels of buffers in between).

---

So if you don't call `Receive`, the data will simply sit in the kernel-mode buffer until you ask for it. If the buffer is full then the packets will simply be dropped, causing lots of connectivity issues. Suffice to say, TCP is meant to be a reliable stream, and does not like dropped packets.

This is why you should deal with your network data as fast as possible. Get it off the thread that is waiting for the data, so that you can continue waiting for more.